# layout не видит библиотеку

Tags: java, android

Импортировал [PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) и в Layout пишу

```
<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh_listview"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

Но почему то проект слетает. При наведении на этот компонент пишет

`Cannot find declaration to go to`

Подскажите, как исправить эту ошибку, может кто сталкивался?

Comment: Как Вы импортировали данную библиотеку? Кстати, а стандартный `SwipeRefreshLayout` не подходит?

Comment: Нет не подходит. Мне нужен был именно BottomRefresLayout. Импортировал, File -> New -> Import Module

Comment: Без библиотек это как????

Comment: С помощью Gradle походу не получится... Там нету ссылки

Comment: А Вас `RecyclerView` устроит?

Comment: На ListView все делается

Comment: `ListView` – это устаревший компонент, на замену которого пришел как раз `RecyclerView`. Впрочем, как хотите. Кстати, `PullToRefreshListView` от Chris Banes уже тоже давно не поддерживается.

Comment: Придется переделать на RecyclerView?

Comment: По-хорошему бы – да. Но я сейчас напишу Вам как реализовать требуемое с помощью обычного `ListView`.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Исходная задача автора была в добавлении элементов в `ListView` при его скролле.

Пусть `int mEventPosition` – это номер элемента `ListView` с конца, при появлении которого необходимо произвести какие-либо действия (`0` – последний элемент, `1` – предпоследний и так далее).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView mMyListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private int mEventPosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mEventPosition = 0;
        mMyListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[]{"one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one"});
        mMyListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mMyListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {}

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if(mAdapter.getCount() - 1 - mMyListView.getLastVisiblePosition() == mEventPosition)
                    Log.d("MY_TAG", "Your action");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что в `if` в методе `onScroll` еще нужно добавить проверку на необходимость его срабатывания (сейчас он выполняется многократно *при скролле по заданному элементу*).

Comment: Почему то при скролле в любом месте страбатывает D/MY_TAG: Your action